# jquery-ui auto-complete only allow search by name from multiple json results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I want to limit search to Names using jqueryUi's auto-complete so that results returned are only Names and don't include other array values like fax and stuff.

Here's my php.

```
<?php
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$req = "SELECT * "
    ."FROM profiles "
    ."WHERE name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) ."%' "; 
$query = mysql_query($req);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $return = array ('label' => $row['name'],
    'founder' => $row['founder'],
    'fax' => $row['fax']

    );

}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
        $( "#SearchInput").autocomplete({
            source: '../Search/BP_Search.php',
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: false,
            select: function(event, ui) {
             $('#ProName' ).html(ui.item.name); 
             $('#ProFax' ).html(ui.item.fax);  
             $('#ProFounder' ).html(ui.item.founder); 
            }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: remove them from your script?

Answer (score 0):

When the `source` is an array of objects - `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`, only the `label` (or `value` if the `label` is not provided) is searched/displayed in the suggestion menu http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. So you can have `fax`, `founder`, and other key/value sets in your returned array and they will not be searched/displayed.

An alternative is that you only get the names in your php script, and then on `select` you do an ajax request to get all other data.

---

note: you are using `ui.item.name` -

```
$('#ProName' ).html(ui.item.name);
```

but `name` in not in your array, so it should be `label`

```
$('#ProName' ).html(ui.item.label);
```